# SwipeRefreshLayout and refresh state

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am struggling with a documentation in `SwipeRefreshLayout` of Google's support library.

When I receive the refresh call using the callback set by `setOnRefreshListener`, I do my action and after that, I found that I need to set the refresh state to false again - if I do NOT do that, I can never trigger it again by swiping!

```
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Refreshing!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //requestDataRefresh();
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

So far, so good. But look at the documentation of `setRefreshing`:

```
/**
 * Notify the widget that refresh state has changed. Do not call this when
 * refresh is triggered by a swipe gesture.
 *
 * @param refreshing Whether or not the view should show refresh progress.
 */
public void setRefreshing(boolean refreshing) {...
```

But setting the refresh state to false again is exactly what I have to do after refreshing!

Is the documentation wrong or am I seeing it wrong?
Shouldn't the doc rather say: "Do not call this with refreshing state true when refresh is triggered by a swipe gesture"??

What do you think?

Comment: We need to set refreshing to false manually like you do, I think the docs is a bit misleading!

Answer (score 3):

When you swipe `SwipeRefreshLayout` from top to bottom, `setRefreshing(true)` is triggered automatically. So you don't need to call `setRefreshing(true)` repeatedly. Meanwhile, if you call `setRefreshing(true)` but not swipe `SwipeRefreshLayout`, you will see the same scene when you swipe `SwipeRefreshLayout`. And no matter whether you call `setRefreshing(true)` or swipe `SwipeRefreshLayout` from top to bottom, you need to call `setRefreshing(false)` after you finish your task. Just like you did in your code segment above.

Answer (score 1):

I think it should probably say that there is no need to call this with true if you're refresh was triggered with the swipe gesture.

Incidentally, I found some issues when updating the UI in certain cases which were solved by wrapping the call like this:

```
private void setRefreshing(final boolean refreshing) {
        if (mSwipeRefreshLayout != null) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(refreshing);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW it would be nicer with lambda
`swipeRefreshLayout.post(() -> swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(refresh));`